# Check if two textbox value is same in php

Tags: php, html, css

I've created a add user page where users can be added to the database, the code is below i would want to compare two textbox and if they are matching(password=conform password) then it should be inserted in the database , how can i achieve that in php

```
<?php
    require("../connect.php");
    error_reporting(0);
    /*
    if(!(adminsessioncheck()))
    header('location:index.php'); */

    if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];


         mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES('','$username','$password')") or die(mysql_error());
   }

?>


   <div style=" width:250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
   <div class="heading1" style="text-align:center">Add a new User</div>
   <br>
   <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="msgbox()">
     <table width="330" height="135" border="0" class="text">
<tr>
    <td><label>User Name</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" required></td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label>Password</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label>Confirm Password</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td align="center"><input type="submit" name="add" value="Add"></td></tr>
</table>
  </form>
 </div>


   </div>
```

Comment: use client side validation (using javascript, jquery etc..)

Comment: @vaibhavmande __client side validation is NOT enough!__ Shahil, it is a very simple task. where you are stucked at?

Comment: @itachi the only thing he is stuck at is if  values, password = cpassword and that can be done by javascript. He will have to do a validation and if the values are not equal return false on form submit.

Comment: Agreed that client side validation is not enough. User can disable javascript.

Comment: `if(trim($passwrod)==trim($confirm_password))`?

Comment: @itachi , rcs Agreed. A server side validation on top of client side validation.

Comment: Well i am new to php as i work on css and html. so i was just wondering how can i match two textbox values and if they are same then it can be inserted to DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.

```
if($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['cpassword']) {
    header("location:index.php")
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES('','$username','$password')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: @ShahilM: `mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'")) > 0`

Comment: I would want to know if i use function msgbox() { alert("New user added.") } on onsubmit=msgbox(); in from it will show the alert box on each submit no matter if its inserted or not. so can i add that script after my insert query so that it will display if the data is only inserted to the DB?

Answer (score 1):

To only check after post you can do this.

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

   if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['cpassword'])
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES('','$username','$password')") or die(mysql_error());
   else
      //create error message

 }
```

But it would be better to check before posting. Also NEVER insert unsanitized data into your database! ever! Plus others will tell you so i might as well mention mysql is deprecated, check out [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        if ($_POST['password']!= $_POST['cpassword'])
        {
        echo("Password did not match! Try again. ");
        }
        else
        {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES('','$username','$password')") or die(mysql_error());
       }
}
```